# The permission of the third digit in mkdir() belongs to who?

Tags: permissions, directory

I'm not good in English and my question is kinda English-ish. All I want to know is the meaning of this sentence:

> The third number specifies permissions for the owner's user group.

I asked this question in an English community and they told me this is a technical question and that's why I'm asking it here. I know it is simple for lots of you guys, but I really cannot understand the users who are mentioned in that sentence. Who are **owner's user group** exactly?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It's not the owner's user group. It's users who are in the group of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Groups are used to logically tie a set of users. You can set permissions on the user level, the group level, and everyone else. This third parameter sets permissions the group that the owner is in.

Answer (score 1):

In linuxy systems, each user belongs to a user group.

The owner in this case is referring to the user who is running the mkdir() command.

Let's say you run the mkdir() command on a non-windows machine. You belong to a certain user group, with a certain set of permissions. The third number of the mode parameter specifies a level of permission for **your user group** - whether or not anyone else in your user group can access that folder you just made.